# What will happen to the ajax call if browser redirects to other page before server responds?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

Practical use case for this scenario is, firing ajax call for a website statistics ( google analytics, omniture, etc. )

Is it enough to server process the request if readyState is 2?

Not sure, I put my question in proper way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When the user loads a different page, any ongoing AJAX calls are aborted. However if the request has been sent to the server, then the server will usually process the request to completion (which may lock things up if you're not careful with sessions!)

If you're using sessions, make sure to call `session_write_close()` to commit the session file and unlock it, thereby allowing a new request to start.

EDIT: Oh yeah, whatever you do, don't do this:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.readyState == 4) {
        if( this.status != 200) alert("Error!");
    }
};
```

Otherwise, a user trying to leave the page would be bombarded by one alert for every aborted AJAX request - either use a custom dialog or don't report errors when `this.status == 0` so that the user may proceed to the next page uninhibited.